# Angular stoorybook - inject service directly

Tags: angular, storybook, angular-storybook

Is there any way , how to inject Angular service into story before init (storybook)? Smth like this.:

```
const Template: Story = (args: Args, myServiceInstance: MyService) => {
  

  return {
    props: args,
    template: ...
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found solution for my problem, how to inject and setup configuration from service , before story init. Simple way for this case is useFactory.

```
 export default {
      title: ...
      component: ...,
      subcomponents: ...
      decorators: [
        moduleMetadata({
          declarations: ...
          providers: [
            {
              provide: MyService,
              useFactory: () => {
                const service = new MyService();
                service.initialSetup(...);
                return service;
              },
            },
          ],
          imports: ...,
        }),
      ],
    } as Meta;
```